# Exception: "No se puede convertir un objeto DBNull en otros tipos"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Tengo la siguiente función que obtiene datos de una DB en Access. Me arroja el error comentado en el encabezado.

Hice un punto de parada, para saber mas o menos en que lugar estaba ocurriendo el error y logré dar que se encontraba en la siguiente linea.

```
p4 = Convert.ToInt32(validacampo(zp_.Rows(cont)("pax_evaden_p4")))
```

Lo que entiendo es que el campo en la base de datos puede venir nulo, por lo que cree la función "validacampo", para que retornara un valor en cero "0" si el valor es nulo, o el valor en caso de no ser nulo.

```
Private Function validacampo(v As Object) As Integer
    If v.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return v
    End If
End Function
```

La siguiente es la función completa que trabaja los datos desde la consulta, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
Private Function ValTotales(ppu As String, sentido As String, conexion As OleDbConnection) As Object
    Dim zp_ As New DataTable
    Dim cont As Integer = 0
    Dim evasores, p1, p2, p3, p4, val, totalusuarios, zp As Integer
    Dim array(4) As Integer
    Dim query_string As String = "SELECT * FROM Evasiones WHERE ppu='" + ppu + "' AND sentido_serv='" + sentido + "'"
    Dim cmm As New OleDbCommand(query_string, conexion)
    Dim dr As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmm)
    dr.Fill(zp_)

    While zp_.Rows.Count > cont
        val += Convert.ToInt32(zp_.Rows(cont)("pax_validan_p1"))
        p1 += Convert.ToInt32(zp_.Rows(cont)("pax_evaden_p1"))
        p2 += Convert.ToInt32(zp_.Rows(cont)("pax_evaden_p2"))
        p3 += Convert.ToInt32(zp_.Rows(cont)("pax_evaden_p3"))

        p4 = Convert.ToInt32(validacampo(zp_.Rows(cont)("pax_evaden_p4")))

        Dim zp_str As String = Convert.ToString(zp_.Rows(cont)("zona_paga"))
        Dim new_str As String = Mid(zp_str, 1, 6)
        If zp_str <> "" And Mid(new_str, 1, 3) = "PAX" Then
            Dim a As Object = Split(new_str, " ")
            If Mid(a(1), 2, 1) = "," Then
                zp += Convert.ToInt32(Mid(a(1), 1, 1))
            Else
                zp += Convert.ToInt32(a(1))
            End If
        End If

        cont += 1
    End While

    evasores = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
    totalusuarios = val + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4

    array(0) = cont
    array(1) = zp
    array(2) = val
    array(3) = evasores
    array(4) = totalusuarios

    Return array

End Function
```

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `If v.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then` por `If v = DBNull.Value Then` en tu funcion `validacampo` a ver si cambia algo...

Comment: Cuando utilizo `If v = DBNull.Value Then ` me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error. `El operador '=' no esta definido para el tipo 'Integer' ni para el tipo 'DBNull'`

Comment: Si,tienes razón perdona. Debes usar `IsDBNull`: `If IsDBNull(v) Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprobar si un valor es `DBNull` en Vb.Net,existe la función [`IsDBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx). En tu código debes hacer algo así:

```
If IsDBNull(v) Then
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto ya pude solucionar el problema!